# Copy-paste annotation from one image to another one in label-studio

Tags: labeling

I have a video of an eye, converted into pngs.
I need to annotate the pupil, with an ellipse. Sometimes the eye does not move, and I would like to annotate the next image with the ellipse/pupil found in the previous image.

How would I do this?
I tried:

- importing json, but this is a bit tedious and its creates a new image/ID.
- `Create copy of current annotation` but the new annotation stays on the same image and can't be pasted in the next similar image.

Thank you very much for your help.